# ReGex for surrounding numbers with whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I would like to find a Regex to convert string like the following one:

```
wienerstr256pta 18 graz austria8051 4
```

Into the following one:

```
wienerstr 256 pta 18 graz austria 8051 4
```

So I just want to surround every number set between spaces.

I know I can easily find the digits by:

```
/[0-9]+/g
```

But how can I replace this match with the same content plus extra whitespaces?

Comment: Is it in JavaScript? Do you have access to the code? Do you need to handle leading/trailing and excessive whitespace?

Comment: Please, add info about programming language or a tool that you use.

Comment: I will use it over Pandas Dataframes in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find all the positions between a non-digit/non-whitespace and a digit, or between a digit and a non-digit/non-whitespace and insert a space there:

```
(?<=[^0-9\s])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9\s])
```

Replace with a space.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hd2GOV/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=[^0-9\s])` - matches a position that is immediately preceded with a char other than a digit and a whitespace...
- `(?=[0-9])` - and is followed with a digit
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[0-9])` - matches a position immediately preceded with a digit and
- `(?=[^0-9\s])` - followed with a char other than a digit and a whitespace.

A Pandas test:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> col_list = ['wienerstr256pta 18 graz austria8051 4']
>>> rx = r'(?<=[^0-9\s])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9\s])'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(col_list, columns=['col'])
>>> df['col'].replace(rx," ", regex=True, inplace=True)
>>> df['col']
0    wienerstr 256 pta 18 graz austria 8051 4
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "wienerstr256pta18graz austria8051 4" \
| sed -r "s/([^0-9])([0-9])/\1 \2/g;s/([0-9])([^0-9])/\1 \2/g;s/  */ /g"

wienerstr 256 pta 18 graz austria 8051 4
```

Replace every change of number to nonnumber or nonnumber to number with both with blank in between. Condense multiple blanks by one in the end, since a blank is a nonnumber too.

Keeping multiple blanks - which might be in the input - together:

```
echo "wienerstr256pta18graz   austria8051 4"     | sed -r "s/([^0-9 ])([0-9])/\1 \2/g;s/([0-9])([^0-9 ])/\1 \2/g;"
wienerstr 256 pta 18 graz   austria 8051 4
```